# Connecting to localhost mysql db with python

Tags: python, mysql

Fair warning: I'm a big time noob. Please handle with kid gloves.

Details:

- Python 3.2
- MySQL 5.5
- Tornado webframe installed
- pymysql installed
- Windows 7

Problem:
I'm following the Tornado documentation on connecting to a mysql database [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/database.html?highlight=mysql). I only want to connect to localhost, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\DIP3\tornado-test.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Connection(localhost,re_project, user=root, password=mypassword, max_idle_time=25200):
NameError: name 'localhost' is not defined
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import pymysql

class Connection(localhost,re_project, user=root, password=mypassword, max_idle_time=25200):
    db = database.Connection("localhost", "re_project")
    for Bogota in db.query("SELECT * FROM cities_copy"):
        print(Bogota.title)
```

MySQL is currently running when I execute the code, so I don't think that should be a problem. What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: don't you have to put it in quotes? "localhost"? ...wait...edit...the traceback looked like code, sorry, lol.

Comment: Why is your application logging into MySQL as root?

Comment: @robert using MySQL as root if it's only listening to localhost is not such a crime.  There are bigger fish to fry here: like the class definition syntax

Comment: @blaxpirit no need to be mean-spirited here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand the problem.  In the documentation, the line `class tornado.database.Connection(host, database, user=None, password=None, max_idle_time=25200)` is part of the documentation and is not meant to be copy/pasted.  That describes how to do the `db = database.Connection` bit.

The green code sample lines should work on their own, as long as 1) the tornado.database module is imported and 2) the `db =` line is adjusted to pass values appropriate for your database to the `Connection` method.

So:

```
from tornado import database  # you can use "import tornado.database" here, but then
                              # you will have to use "tornado.database.Connection()"
                              # instead of "database.Connection()"

db = database.Connection("localhost", "re_project", user="root", password="mypassword")
for bogota in db.query("SELECT * FROM cities_copy"):  # I changed "bogota" to lower-case because the convention in Python is for only classes, not objects, to have upper-case names.
    print(bogota.title)
```

I haven't tested this because I do not have Python 3.2 installed, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll try to adjust.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for your help! I updated my code based on your comments and I got a global name error in the databases.py tornado file. I opened the file and it seems like it's looking for mysqldb to be installed. I did find the line causing the error and tried deleting it and next got this error: ERROR:root:Cannot connect to MySQL on localhost

I don't know how helpful any of this is, I might just be a bit over my head here. Any feedback would be appreciated, but not expecting a miracle :)

Comment: Okay, well, you really do need mysqldb installed in order to interface with mysql.  Restore that file to it's previous state (you can't delete a line and expect it to work!) and install the mysqldb package for python -- how you do that depends on your operating system -- and try again.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit in my OP. As far as I know mysqldb does not support Python 3. So I have pymysql installed instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what the solution is to that and I couldn't find it easily on Google.  Search StackOverflow for "tornado python 3 mysql" and if you don't find anything, maybe ask another question about that specifically: How to use Tornado with Python 3 and mysql, when it says it requires mysqldb and that is not supported on Python 3 yet.  I suspect the answer will be to use a comparable DBAPI-compatible library in its place, but hopefully someone who has handled this specific problem will have more detailed advice for you.

Comment: thanks for your help Andrew, I'll do as you suggested. Next time I'll be more careful before I post a question too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
class Connection(localhost,re_project, user=root, password=mypassword, max_idle_time=25200):
```

makes no sense at all. You can't define a class like that. Did you mean to use `def` instead of `class`?

Comment: +1 here.  Obviously it would be nice to give a "solution" of working code, but it's unclear what the OP wanted to do -- so best to just point out the main issue

Comment: blah, sorry--I must be missing something fundamental because I thought by just copying the example from the documentation would substitute for my lack of knowledge in python. I'll review the syntax and revise my question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually defining a constructor.  Look at this as a template for what you need to do:

```
class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self, host, project, user, password, max_idle_time):
        self.db = database.Connection(
            host, project, user=user, password=password, max_idle_time=max_idle_time)

    def some_other_method(self):
        for bogota in self.db.query("SELECT * FROM cities_copy"):
            print(bogota.title)
```

Comment: This is what I originally thought too, just looking at the error message, but now that I look at the code properly it's clear the parameters for connecting to the database don't belong in that place at all.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. As I commented in Daniel's answer, I guess I don't have the fundamentals down yet, so I'll have to review proper syntax and try to figure out where I'm getting confused.